# Change boot order using "efibootmgr -o " command

Tags: efibootmgr

While changing the boot order using the `efibootmgr -o` command, I am facing duplication of UEFI items after reboot. Please see below for the steps I followed.

1. Boot to OS (I used Ubuntu 18.10):

   ```
   root@XXX:~$ efibootmgr
   BootCurrent: 0001
   Timeout: 3 seconds
   BootOrder: 0001,0002, 0003
   Boot0001* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell
   Boot0002* UEFI: hp x705w PMAP, Partition 1
   Boot0003* Hard Drive
   ```
2. Now modify the boot order:

   ```
   root@XXX: ~$ efibootmgr -o 2, 3
   BootCurrent: 0001
   Timeout: 3 seconds
   BootOrder: 0002, 003
   Boot0001* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell
   Boot0002* UEFI: hp x705w PMAP, Partition 1
   Boot0003* Hard Drive
   ```
3. Reboot and check. There will be duplication found for `UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell`:

   ```
   root@XXX: ~$ efibootmgr 
   BootCurrent: 0001
   Timeout: 3 seconds
   BootOrder: 0004, 0002, 0003, 0001
   **Boot0001* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell**
   Boot0002* UEFI: hp x705w PMAP, Partition 1
   Boot0003* Hard Drive
   **Boot0004* UEFI: Built-in EFI Shell**
   ```

I request someone's help to understand why this duplication happens.

**NOTE:** The duplication happens only for the devices that are been skipped while changing the boot order.

Comment: I’d guess it’s some sort of incompatibility between your bios and efibootmgr. It’s meant to be possible to remove the extra entry with sudo efibootmgr -b 4 -B where the 4 specifies Boot0004. Substitute -A for the -B to make that entry inactive. However since this appears buggy on your system I’d be inclined to leave well alone as long as it works